# ¿Cómo convierto la animación de flip que tengo con hover en javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo la animación creada en el hover, pero me gustaría que se ejecutase apretando el botón que he creado en vez de pasando el cursor por encima del div. Éste es el  código:

```js
var vuelta = document.getElementsByClassName("prueba");

function Animacion() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('prueba', 'detras');
  console.log("Hello world!");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.texto {
  margin: 15px;
}

.prueba {
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.prueba:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.delante:hover {
  display: none !important;
}

.delante,
.detras {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.delante {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translatey(-500px);
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.detras {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.cajitas {
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

button {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja cajitas prueba" id="caja1">
  <div class="delante">
    <div class="texto"><strong>Hola</strong></div>
    <button onclick="Animacion()">Descripcion</button>
  </div>
  <div class="detras">
    <strong>Adios</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo cambios mínimos en tu código:

1. En lugar de poner los cambios de estilos en `:hover` haz que apliquen a una clase (yo la he llamado `.flip` pero puedes usar el nombre que quieras). Para eso sólo tienes que cambiar:

   ```
   .prueba:hover {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }

   .delante:hover {
     display: none !important;
   }
   ```

   a esto:

   ```
   .prueba.flip {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }

   /*.delante:hover {
     display: none !important;
   } -- realmente esto no hace falta */
   ```
2. Añade/quita esa clase a la caja dentro de la función `Animacion` usando `toggle`. Para eso, cambia el código HTML que tiens a esto:

   ```
   var vuelta = document.querySelector(".prueba");

   function Animacion() {
     vuelta.classList.toggle("flip");
   }
   ```

Cambiando esas pocas líneas de código ya hace lo que quieres (he añadido un botón para que vuelva atrás también):

```js
var vuelta = document.querySelector(".prueba");

function Animacion() {
  vuelta.classList.toggle("flip");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.texto {
  margin: 15px;
}

.prueba {
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.prueba.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/*.delante:hover {
  display: none !important;
}*/

.delante,
.detras {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.delante {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translatey(-500px);
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.detras {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.cajitas {
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

button {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja cajitas prueba" id="caja1">
  <div class="delante">
    <div class="texto"><strong>Hola</strong></div>
    <button onclick="Animacion()">Descripcion</button>
  </div>
  <div class="detras">
    <strong>Adios</strong>
    <button onclick="Animacion()">Descripcion</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi te puse 2 metodos:

1. dandole `click` directo al `div`
2. dandole `click` el `button`

```js
    // seleccionamos el elemento con la clase prueba
    // no usamos getElementsByClassName porque no se le puede agregar el evento click
    let vuelta = document.querySelector(".prueba");
  // seleccionamos el stylo de vuelta
    let deg = vuelta.style;

    // agregamos un evento click y pasamos el evento
    vuelta.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
     // e.target devolvera el elemento al que se le dio click y validamos que sea delante
     if(e.target.className =="delante" ){
         // e.currentTarget devuelve el elemento al que se le asigno el click "vuelta"
         // podriamos poner tambien deg.transform ="rotateY(180deg)"; es lo mismo
        // aplicamos a el div vuelta un transform de 180deg 
        e.currentTarget.style.transform ="rotateY(180deg)";
      }else{
        // en caso de no ser delante es atras asi que regresamos la rotacion a 0
        e.currentTarget.style.transform ="rotateY(0deg)";
      }
    });
    
// ahora con un button
// seleccionamos el button
let btn = document.querySelector("button");

// creamos un evento click
btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{

  // validamos que su stylo sea nada o rotateY(0deg)
 if(deg.transform == "" || deg.transform == "rotateY(0deg)"){
   // si lo es le aplicamos un rotateY(180deg)
    deg.transform ="rotateY(180deg)";
 }else{
   // en caso contrario lo regresamos a 0deg
   deg.transform ="rotateY(0deg)";
 }
})
```

```css
  * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    body {
        
        height: 100vh;
        
    }


    .texto {
        margin: 15px;
    }


    .prueba{
        transition:  1s ease;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;


    }

    /*.prueba:hover {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .delante:hover{
      display: none !important; 
    }*/

    .delante , .detras{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .delante{
        z-index: 2;
        transform: translatey(-500px);
        margin-top: 500px;
    }
    .detras{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        border-radius: 10px;
        
    }



    .cajitas {
        height: 250px;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 10px;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

```html
<button>clickme</button> 
<br>
<div class="caja cajitas prueba" id="caja1">
      <div class="delante">
         <strong>Hola</strong>
       </div>
      <div class="detras">
        <strong>Adios</strong>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿has notado un comportamiento raro en el snippet? Si lo ejecuto en modo edición (en el modal), la animación funciona sin problemas; pero si lo ejecuto como parte de la respuesta (dándole al botón ejecutar) se ve diferente (la tarjeta cambia de negro a blanco sin motivo aparente). Me ocurre lo mismo en mi respuesta, no sé si es un bug de los snippets o de mi navegador.

Comment: debes ver el cambio en el css que hice tambien :v

Comment: No me refiero a eso. Veo tu código bien y que se ejecuta bien, pero parece haber un bug con los snippets. Dale a "Ejecutar" en tu respuesta y dale al botón de "clickme". En mi caso veo que después de cambiar la tarjeta a "Adios", ésta se vuelve blanca. Pero si le das a editar tu respuesta, después a "editar este fragmento de código" y finalmente a "Ejecutar" dentro del modal, eso no ocurre y se ve la animación bien. Se ve bien en un sitio pero mal en el otro. Ocurre igual con mi respuesta :-/

Comment: no sabria decirte, debes agregar lo que te sale a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte en caso de que creas que es un bug del mismo` snippets` ya no podria hacer nada en ese caso.

Comment: Lo único que quería saber es si ves también el problema para reportarlo a StackExchange, porque no sé si soy solo yo. Pero no importa, les enviaré un mensaje de todos modos si no lo ha hecho ya nadie.